# (Javascript) Buttons are not updating

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a list of ingredients and selected ingredients displayed. When I click on an ingredient, I want it to appear under my selected ingredients and when I click on the selected ingredient, I want it to go back.

This is what I have so far.
http://jsfiddle.net/inspiredtolive/ghpus6on/3/

```
function forEach(array, action) {
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        action(array[i]);
    }
}

function printIngredButtons(array, selected) {
    forEach(array, function (ingredient) {
    Buttons += '<button onclick="moveToOther(' + ingredient + ')">' + ingredient + '</button><br>';
    });

    if(!selected) {
        document.getElementById("ingred").innerHTML = Buttons;
        Buttons = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("selected").innerHTML = Buttons;
        Buttons = "";
    }
}

function printAllButtons() {
    printIngredButtons(ingredients, false);
    printIngredButtons(selected, true);
}

function moveToOther(ingredient) {
    var index = -1;
    if(ingredients.indexOf(ingredient) > -1) {
        ingredients.splice(index, 1);
        selected.push(ingredient);
        printAllButtons();
    }
    else if(selected.indexOf(ingredient) > -1){
        selected.splice(index, 1);
        ingredients.push(ingredient);
        printAllButtons();
    }
}


var ingredients = ["eggs", "cheese", "milk"];
var Buttons = "";

var selected = ["peanut butter"];


printAllButtons();
```

Comment: You have to mention what is the problem in your code instead of dumping the whole code and expecting us to find problem / clean up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to `moveToOther` are not enclosed in quotes, so they are interpreted as variable names. This is why the error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: eggs is not defined` will appear in the console if the "eggs" button is clicked, for example.

The line to create the button markup should be changed to this:

```
Buttons += '<button onclick="moveToOther(\'' + ingredient + '\')">' + ingredient + '</button><br>';
```

A second issue is that you are always removing the element at index -1 instead of the index of the clicked item. The `moveToOther` function should be changed to use the actual index.

```
function moveToOther(ingredient) {
    //Save the actual index values here instead of hard-coding -1
    var ingredientsIndex = ingredients.indexOf(ingredient);
    var selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(ingredient);

    if(ingredientsIndex > -1) {
        ingredients.splice(ingredientsIndex, 1);
        selected.push(ingredient);
        printAllButtons();
    }
    else if(selectedIndex > -1){
        selected.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
        ingredients.push(ingredient);
        printAllButtons();
    }
}
```

An updated JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/brLexrg0/.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also realized I was not passing in the right index for splicing.

Comment: @MarcoChan Glad I could help. The second part of my answer addresses the splicing index. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.